# How to import office 365 usage analytics data to SQL DB using azure data factory

Tags: azure, odata, azure-data-factory, o365-flow, sqldb

I would like to import office 365 usage analytics dataset to our SQL DB using azure data factory pipelines on month on month basis.
Because it only keeps for sometime and we want to keep historic data.

I have tried to connect to Odata(https://reports.office.com/pbi/v1.0/a1fdea56-3201-4d00-9b76-661338850557) in azure data factory it gives the following error, when I have configured source as Odata it gives table list in path of linked service but when I try to preview data it gives the following error.
[successfully gives tables list](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i5SO4.png)
Error code
23223
Details
Supported content type could not be found from response of serviceurl or serviceurl+"/$metadata", please check the response from your other client such as browser.
A supported MIME type could not be found that matches the content type of the response. None of the supported type(s) 'application/json;odata.metadata=minimal;odata.streaming=true;IEEE754Compatible=false, application/json;odata.metadata=minimal;odata.streaming=true;IEEE754Compatible=true, application/json;odata.metadata=minimal;odata.streaming=true, application/json;odata.metadata=minimal;odata.streaming=false;IEEE754Compatible=false, application/json;odata.metadata=minimal;odata.streaming=false;IEEE754Compatible=true, application/json;odata.metadata=minimal;odata.streaming=false, application/json;odata.metadata=minimal;IEEE754Compatible=false, application/json;odata.metadata=minimal;IEEE754Compatible=true, application/json;odata.metadata=minimal, application/json;odata.metadata=full;odata.streaming=true;IEEE754Compatible=false, application/json;odata.metadata=full;odata.streaming=true;IEEE754Compatible=true, application/json;odata.metadata=full;odata.streaming=true, application/json;odata.metadata=full;odata.streaming=false;IEEE754Compatible=false, application/json;odata.metadata=full;odata.streaming=false;IEEE754Compatib...' matches the content type 'text/html; charset=utf-8'.
Activity ID: 512b0432-ee06-4954-9772-4f13422395bd
[while preview data it gives this error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6mtqX.png)

Answer (score 0):

Importing `OData` to Azure SQL Database faces compatibility issues and therefore isn't a good practice.

You can try add the data using Power BI desktop using the below format and it should work fine.

```
OData.Feed("https://myclient.crm2.dynamics.com/api/data/v8.1/", null, [Implementation="2.0"])
```

Comment: The OP isn't using PowerBI. As for the opinion about compatibility issues - that should be a comment, not an answer.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but we are customizing the O365 usage analytics report in Power BI, we connected the data through Odata feed-https://reports.office.com/pbi/v1.0/a1fdea56-3201-4d00-9b76-661338850557
and it is successfully connected.
Now here we have two table UserActivity and UserState which has one month data where it gets refreshed every month and so we wanted to save the historic data for analysis. 
So, we are trying to store the month on month data in Azure SQL DB with the help of copy activity in Azure Data Factory. Please could you help how do we go forward?